# Problems in playing Fairplay Encrypted content on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, fairplay

We are trying to write player in Javascript which should play fairplay encrypted content on safari browser. We figured 'encrypted' event is not supported on Safari browser and we added event listener for 'WebKitNeedKey' event. We coded the flow as below.

```
addEventListener('webkitneedkey, onWebKitNeedKey);
onWebKitNeedKey(evt) {
    videoElement = document.getElementById('videoID');
    if (videoElement.webkitKeys) {
        videoElement.webkitSetMediaKeys(new WebKitMediaKeys('com.apple.fps.2_0'));
    }
    const session = videoElement.webkitKeys.createSession('video/mp4', event.initData);
    session.addEventListener('webkitkeymessage', onWebKitKeyMessage);
    session.addEventListener('webkitkeyerror', onWebKitKeyError);
    session.addEventListener('webkitkeyadded', onWebKitKeyAdded);
}
onWebKitKeyMessage(evt) {
    console.log(`received webkit key message : ${evt}`);
}
onWebKitKeyError(evt) {
    console.log(`received webkit key error : ${evt}`);
}
onWebKitKeyAdded(evt) {
    console.log(`received webkit key added : ${evt}`);
}
```

Now I am getting the webkitneedkey event and after setting the keys, I am getting webkitkeymessage event. I am planning to implement the logic of contacting the server for the license as per https://github.com/WebPlatformForEmbedded/WPEWebKit/blob/master/LayoutTests/http/tests/media/clearkey/clear-key-hls-aes128.html

I have following questions. Can any one please help me to resolve the below questions?

```
 1) Do we need to set the source to '.m3u8'? Is it mandatory? I am getting the events even without setting the source to .m3u8
 2) Is my approach correct in onWebKitNeedKey? Can I send evt.initData directly to webkitSetMediaKeys without modifying? Do I need to extract the content ID from evt.initData if I use key as 'com.apple.fps.2_0' instead of 'com.apple.fps.1_0'?
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? Can you help me to know how to play DRM on safari browse. I am using shaka-player